# Costly StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `CheckBox` style that I use over multiple `UserControl`s, ~100 in each one. Then, when I try and use these `UserControl`s, it can take several seconds to load. I have tracked it down to my style using an image, as when I comment it out, everything works just fine.

Is there a way to load the image in once, then use that local copy in the styles? Or maybe do that with the whole style in each of the `UserControl`s?

This is the style,

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Image Source="/Images/Unchecked.png">
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Have you tried making it an ACTUAL static resource {StaticResource xxx}? Also Grid layout is "expensive", why have two of them just to contain an image?

Comment: In my `UserControl`s, I merge the dictionary that the style is in, then do that, `<CheckBox ... Style="{StaticResource MyCheckBoxStyle}"/>`

Comment: And I edited a couple things out that don't matter, 2 pointless grids are the result.

Comment: I meant make the image a static resource. I believe if you make the style a static resource, it will still dynamically resolve the crap inside of it. You have to make the inside crap a static resource.

Comment: Just tried doing that, `<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImage" UriSource="/Images/Unchecked.png"/>`, then in the style, `<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImage}"/>`. No noticeable change in time to load

Comment: If you put something else in there? Like a button, or even a rectangle, does it have the same slow down?

Comment: If you mean instead of the image, there is only a button, etc, then no, no slow down

Comment: Is your image simple enough to draw with a path? There is some anecdotal evidence that loading lots of images will slow down performance. Better to "draw" them using path syntax if possible.

Comment: It probably is, but I am unaware of the technique that you are talking about.

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx ... if a button renders fast, then the path should as well... you can try with a simple path first to see if your performance issue is gone before trying to figure out the syntax. No point wasting time figuring it out if it doesn't :).

Comment: If I used a simple one correctly, then it might work, however it looks pretty complicated, and I'm not sure my time would be suited to learning this. My image might be simple enough, but having never used `Path` before, it might not be. If need be, I'll give it a shot. Until then, I'll keep looking for other solutions. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You don't make the paths manually... its too complicated like you said. You can export XAML from Adobe Illustrator :). But if you want to test, you can try one of the ones here: http://modernuiicons.com/  just click one, and at the top, it will give you the path syntax. Then just paste that in your template and run and see if the performance is better for you.

Comment: I tested it out a bit, and the performance is much better, and I think I'm going to go with this, so thank you. However, now I'm curious if my original plan is possible (just for sake of knowing)

Comment: The other benefits of using path is that its all vector based, so graphics scale perfectly with no jaggies or fuzziness and you can do cool animations and stuff. Those icons are flat and one color, but I've seen some path graphics that were amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BitmapImage once and reuse it:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="UncheckedBitmap" UriSource="/Images/Unchecked.png"/>
...
<Image Source="{StaticResource UncheckedBitmap}"/>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't make it much faster for some reason.